# How to calculate real probability with multiple scenarios?

Tags: probability

I would like to know how to calculate the probability of being profitable on an event where there are multiple scenarios. For example paying 5 dollars to grab a bill from a box box full of bills where there is a 1% chance of grabbing a 100 dollar bill, a 5% chance of grabbing a 20 dollar bill, a 10% of grabbing a 10 dollar bill and a 84% chance of grabbing a 1$ bill.

The first 3 scenarios would be profitable but the last one wouldn't. My question is, how do I calculate the real probability of being profitable? I thought about just adding the probabilities and that would give a 16% chance of being profitable but I don't know if I should apply some additional logic to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the payout ratio.

From this case you 1 in 100 chance of drawing the \$100 bill so that average payout ratio is \$1. (win once, lose 99 times).
So in this case with multiple different payouts:

\$100 * 1% = \$1
\$20 * 5% = \$1
\$10 * 10% = \$1
\$1 * 84% = \$0.84

So summing up all of these values equals \$3.84. This is the predictive long term average of every play.  Since the payout is less than the investment, it is not a very good game.
Note this payout ratio is better than most lotteries.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, never thought about calculating payout ratio for long term average return but, if I wanted to do the experiment only one time, is 16% chance a correct approach?

Comment: Yes, for a single play, a 16% chance of drawing a 10, 20 or 100 dollar bill